# How can my child component call a method on the parent component in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

#### Background

Suppose I have some parent component, call it `MatchList`, that presents a list of `Hero` objects, among other things. Each `Hero` object has properties that are shown in some table. Now suppose I also have a button for each `Hero` that *updates the route*, loads a new view, and shows more details.

Before

> http://heroic.com/match-list

After

> http://heroic.com/hero-84

#### Problem

My problem essential is this: I want to call the router's `navigate()` method from a button in my `MatchList` template, but I receive the following error when I attempt to do so:

> EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ ...
>   angular2.dev.js:21835 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: l_context.setPath is not a function...
>   angular2.dev.js:21835 TypeError: l_context.setPath is not a function at ...

**In other words** It looks like I cannot reference the parent component's router methods in the child template.

So, what is the correct and best way in Angular 2 for a child component access the methods of the parent component ( or 'context')?

I'd prefer if the solution was something cleaner than

```
class parent {

     child: Child;

     constructor(...) {

        ...

        this.child.parent = this;

     }
}
```

#### Sample Code

**EDIT**
I changed my template button to

```
(^click)="setPath(match.match_id)"
```

I am not longer receiving an error message, but nothing happens - I don't even get a console log confirming the click.

---

Snippets of what I have so far.

//Parent

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'dota-app',
        directives: [Home, MatchesView, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
        templateUrl: 'AppView.html'
    })
    @RouteConfig([
        { path: '/', component: Home, as: 'Home' },
        { path: '/matches', component: MatchesView, as: 'Matches' },
        { path: '/match-details', component: MatchDetailsView, as: 'MatchDetails'}
    ])
    export class RootDotaComponent {

        router: Router;

        constructor(router: Router) {

            this.router = router;

        }

        public setPath(linkParams: any[]|string): void {

            if (typeof linkParams === "string")
                linkParams = [linkParams];

            this.router.navigate(<any[]>linkParams);

        }

    }

}
```

//Child

```
@Component({
    selector: 'matches-view',
    providers: [DotaRestDao],
})
@View({
    templateUrl: './components/MatchesView/MatchesView.html',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class MatchesView {

    public result;

    private dataService: DotaRestDao;

    constructor(dataService: DotaRestDao) {

        this.result = { matches: [] };

        this.dataService = dataService;

        this.dataService.getData({
            baseUrl: DotaRestDao.MATCH_HISTORY_BASE
        }).subscribe(
            res => this.result = res.result,
            err => console.log("something wrongable", err),
            () => console.log('completed')
        );

    }

}
```

//Template

```
<table class="table">
              ...
    <button (click)="setPath(match.match_id)">Match Detail Route</button>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you put an event on your component and let the parent change the route when it gets it?

Comment: Seems promising but no dice so far. I changed my button to `(^click)="setPath(match.match_id)"`, notice the carat. Did you have something else in mind? Not sure if I'm up to speed on events.

Comment: Your child component is calling setPath() which is a function you made that only exists on the parent. (The error is telling you that it cant find that function) You will likely need a middleman function to take the event from the child to the parent as I don't think you can call parent functions from child templates. I could be wrong though...

Comment: Right, I need a way to access a higher-level context. Angular must have an out-of-the-box way to do this, right?

Comment: I was thinking `<matches-view (selectHero)="changeRouteToHero($event)">`, then generate the selectHero event from your component to let the parent handle it and change the route with the changeRouteToHero method.

Comment: This sounds promising. Can you point me to an example of this logic so I can see how everything gets wired together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of this question, namely calling a parent `router`, the answer, it turns out, is trivial. See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UGIbAayNvGlwJWZOtPAA?p=preview) for details.

The main takeaway is that giving a router to a child component a la

```
class ChildComponent {

    constructor(router: Router) {

        ...

    }

}
```

does *not* create a new router, it merely extends the existing router of the parent component. Thus, the need to a reference to the parent object is obviated. Just call the methods of the childRouter and everything works as expected.