# How can a component in Angular 2 pop up another component by invoking its method?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've designed a popup component and it's intended to show and hide by invokation of the following methods setting *back* and *front* variables that the class of it is bound to.

```
hide() {
  this.back = this.back.replace(/[ ]?shown/, "");
  this.front = this.front.replace(/[ ]?shown/, "");
}

show() {
  this.back += "shown";
  this.front += "shown";
}
```

The problem is that I wish the popup to be invokeable from other components, without it being a part of them. In fact, the markup for the application I'm aiming at is as follows.

```
<navbar></navbar>
<sidebar></sidebar>
<filter></filter>
<poppy></poppy>
```

I'm not sure how to invoke it, though. I'm reacting to a click in the navigation bar and detecting that the request is supposed to trigger the popup to pop up.

```
if(notImplementedYet) {
  ???
}
```

I've googled the issue but I'm not really getting a clear image of the proper way to approach it. For instance, I've seen something about `Input` and `Output` [here](http://mean.expert/2016/05/21/angular-2-component-communication/) but I can't judge if it's even remotely applicable for my need.

I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664358/how-can-my-child-component-call-a-method-on-the-parent-component-in-angular-2) but it doesn't tell me much, possibly due to lack of experience with Angular. Also, I worry that the parent-to-child/child-to-parent approach will result in a very nasty invokation structure.

Comment: It's common to use a service for inter-component communication. See an [example of implementation here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4204194). It shows how any component in the app can show/trigger a SpinnerComponent via a service. I think you could adapt it to your situation.  Also, check out the [other techniques](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) for component communication in the official doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @Output in the component from which you want to invoke the popup. You can then simply use template variable to invoke the show or hide methods in the popup component.

For example, you can show your popup when clicking in nav bar by the code:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html'
})
export class NavComponent {
    @Output() onClickNav: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); 
    onClick():void {
        this.onClickNav.emit(null);
    }
}

<navbar (onClickNav)="popup.show()"></navbar>
<poppy #popup ></poppy>
```

Comment: check the answer in this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460418/angular-2-ng2-bootstrap-parent-component-call-modal-show-in-child-component-n/42463516#42463516

Comment: It seems to do the job. +1 for clarity. Now, I tried to send in an object instead of *null* like this: `this.onClickNav.emit({donkey:"ass"})`. However, I'm not sure how to connect it to the `popup.show(???)` part when invoking. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child).

Basically you can instance a `ViewChild` variable which reference the child component and then you can call its methods.

Comment: How does it work when the path between children/parents is long? I see maintenance issues... Suggestions?