# How to provide data when emiting via EventEmitter in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, events

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42508655/1525840), I can define an event emitter to my output.

```
export class NavComponent {
  @Output() poof: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); 
  onClick():void { this.poof.emit(null); }
}
```

Then, I can emit the event to the markup according to the below.

```
<navbar (poof)="catcher.boom()"></navbar>
<compa #catcher></compa>
```

I tried to provide an object instead of `null` using `this.poof.emit({});` and altering the markup by `catcher.boom(input)`. That didn't work and the console tells me that the input is undefined.

How can I provide an object using the setup above? Is there a wiser approach?

Comment: try using (poof)="catcher.boom(`$event`)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the implicit `$event` variable that provides the emitted value

```
<navbar (poof)="catcher.boom($event)"></navbar>
```

Comment: I got stuck on trying to push an object down the throat of `@Output(throat-here)`. Now I feel almost stupid for not trying your approach.